# How do I create a shared ID-space for two classes?

Tags: java

I have two classes: *Engine* and *Trainset* (multiple unit) and both classes share their ID-space which consists of a name and a series `id=<series>-<name>`.

This is my *Engine* class (it's abstract because there are subtypes of engines (DieselEngine, SteamEngine, ...):

```
public abstract class Engine extends RollingStock {
    private String name;
    private String series;

    public Engine(int length, boolean couplingFront, boolean couplingBack, String name, String series) {
        super(length, couplingFront, couplingBack);
        this.name = name;
        this.series = series;
    }
}
```

and here is my *Trainset* class

```
public class Trainset extends RollingStock {
    private String name;
    private String series;

    public Trainset(int length, boolean couplingFront, boolean couplingBack, String name, String series) {
        super(length, couplingFront, couplingBack);
        this.name = name;
        this.series = series;
    }
}
```

So both classes have the attribute name and series.

Now, I created another class *SharedIdSpace* to ensure that they use the same ID-space. However, I have no idea how I should implement this cleverly...

Comment: Implement what cleverly? A class with 2 fields in it? There is nothing to be clever about. I don't understand what the problem is in here.

Comment: Don't know your project as a whole, but I'd suggest to create another class (say it "Identification") that contains only name and series. And then, instead of having name and series in your two classes above, just keep a reference to an instance of Identification.

Comment: My suggest, you should distingush is-A and has-A relationship first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being you could create a new base class:

```
class IdSpaceRollingStock extends RollingStock {
    protected final String name;
    protected final String series;
    public IdSpaceRollingStock (int length, boolean couplingFront, boolean couplingBack,
            String name, String series) {
        super(length, couplingFront, couplingBack);
        this.name = name;
        this.series = series;
    }
    ...
}

public abstract class Engine extends IdSpaceRollingStock {
public abstract class Trainset extends IdSpaceRollingStock {
```

This might be a temporary solution as it charges the inheritance structure with an artificial class.

However it is the most minimal solution, with least additional code. Override equals and hashCode there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you check my solution approach?

Comment: On `id=series+"-"+name`. On such cases it often is better to have a wrapping class with the set of operations on the data. Like the java Locale, LocalDate, Color and such. And then inheritance is not really needed. Using a String could result in repeated code. With errors like using `id.split("-")[1]`.